# Jquery Animation Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, animation

I want to make a slider moving smoothly up and down. How can this be done?

```
 $(scroller).scroll(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var that = $(e.target);

    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
        $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {

           that.scrollTop(slide(that.scrollTop()));     

        }, 200));

})

function slide(s){

    var currentIndex = Math.round(s/600);           
    return 600*currentIndex;
}
```

Everything crashes after trying the .animate() function...
Full code here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/jovial-feather-cq1zd?fontsize=14

Comment: Add the HTML to test it and where is the `.animate()` ?

Comment: Here is the full code please help me with the animation. I don't know where to put the animate() function and how to do it for example.   https://codesandbox.io/embed/jovial-feather-cq1zd?fontsize=14